# Load Wikipedia page and print locally

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, printing

This is a weird one. I am attempting the following.

I have a local HTML and JavaScript file which generates a random Wikipedia page. When I get the URL for the random Wikipedia page I want to send it to the printer. However, both Chrome and Firefox seem to have a real problem with this.

In Chrome I get an error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/w/index.php?title=Popran_National%20Park&printable=yes from frame with URL my local
file. Domains, protocols and ports must match. </br>
gol.js:99Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'print'
```

In Firefox:

```
Permission denied to access property 'print' </br>
[Break On This Error] </br>
infoWindow.print();
```

Do you think this could be a because I am running things locally?

My code for spawning the new window is:

```
var printURL = "https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/w/index.php?"
infoWindow = window.open(printURL,'wiki');
setTimeout ( "printWin()", 2000 );
```

where `printWin()` is:

```
function printWin(){
    infoWindow.print();
    infoWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: A website cannot execute things on another; it's called the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

It's the security policy stuff that you are running into.  Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

What you need to do is run the GET request for the Wiki page through a server.  So the server acts as a proxy.  The browser will allow this because, from it's perspective, the content is from the same origin as your hosting page.

You might get broken links still.  You might have to come up with way to proxy all of that as well -- or rewrite the HTML.  If you do that, now you are getting into the land of copyright and I'm not sure what's what when it comes to all that.

Are you allowed to proxy Wikipedia content through a server, thereby masking its origin?  Maybe you are as long as you don't change the content.  But if you adjust the HTML to make it look like it was meant to look, then are you being a bad boy or a good boy? I have no idea whatsoever on this.

I think I answered your technical question though.

Comment: Hey there thanks 1461 i will look into those links you sent. Regarding the legality I think that it should be fine as I am not altering the content in anyway. will read up on that some more too :)